How to Display Monetary Field in Odoo 15 Qweb Report?
I need to add amount field in a qweb report. Both t-field and t-esc have not worked. All currency configurations are ok.  Here is the code:
<span t-esc="o.amount_total" t-options="{'widget': 'monetary', 'display_currency': o.currency_id}"/>

See the current behavior at this link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1W67DSW5RxvPV4QH-pPVoLaiwhg5dpvUW
